# Difference between Fermions and electrons

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin, spin-statistics, quantum-statistics

I'm confused between fermions and electrons. For example say I have a system comprises of three electrons and there are three single particle energy level accessible to each of three electrons.
What will be the possible configuration for electrons and in this example, what will be the possible configuration for fermions?

Another question I have whenever we talk about fermions and electrons, they don't fill simultaneously in energy state.  For example let’s say I have 2 fermions and 2 electrons. And there are 4 energy level for these electrons and fermions. What will be the possible configuration for this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the short answer is: Electrons are one possible type of fermions. So, each electron is a fermion but not each fermion is an electron. Therefore electrons as all the other fermions behave in the same way when it comes to quantum number configurations.

To give more background: Fermions are arbitrary particles with half-integer spin. Bosons are arbitrary particles with integer spin. So electrons, muons, tau leptons and the corresponding neutrinos, as well as all the quarks and baryons are fermions. The interaction particles (photon, W and Z boson, gluon and the hypothetical graviton) as well es mesons are bosons.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons are one kind of fermion. The ways electrons fill energy levels follow from energy minimisation subject to the exclusion principle. The only options the exclusion principle rules out are those in which two fermions of the same type share a state. For example, an electron can share its state with a muon, which is a different type of fermion.

Atoms containing a muon are occasionally produced, but a more relevant example of mixing multiple fermion types is an atomic nucleus. Protons and neutrons are also types of fermion, and they form shells of their own similar to electrons. However, what protons do in terms of occupying states has no bearing on what neutrons can do.